# setValue is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-forms

I'm building a data-driven form in Ionic 2, with a few fields. I'm trying to manually update the value of one control, when the value of the form changes. However, I'm getting this error: `TypeError: _this.myForm.controls.name.setValue is not a function`. I have tried both with and without the `<FormControl>` type cast, but the error remains.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
     templateUrl: 'build/pages/lead-provider/add-bp/add-bp.html',
     directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
 })
 export class AddBpPage {
     private myForm: FormGroup;

     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
         this.myForm= formBuilder.group({
             'name': ['', [Validators.required]],
             'email': ['', [Validators.required]],
             'phone': ['', [Validators.required]]
         });

         this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
             (<FormControl>this.myForm.controls['name']).setValue('abc');
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: What does `(<FormControl>this.myForm.controls['name'])` return? The cast to `FormControl` shouldn't be necessary anymore AFAIK. What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: The version currently used by Ionic2, rc4. The cast returns a FormControl object

Answer (score 2):

`setValue` was added 2 weeks ago. Therefore RC.4 can't contain it yet.

Use instead `updateValueAndValidity()`